# ¿Qué función cumple la palabra "café" en «Café bar»?

Tags: sustantivos, adjetivos, sintaxis, categorías-gramaticales

Esto es lo típico que ves todos los días pero nunca te planteas: hoy, al llegar al bar donde suelo almorzar los viernes, me he quedado parado en la puerta leyendo el cartelito de la entrada:

> CAFÉ BAR

Parece como si "café" fuese un adjetivo de "bar" pero, hasta donde yo sé, [**café**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6bQcjCM) es un sustantivo (y no, el bar no era marrón).

¿Qué función cumple "café" aquí: modifica a "bar" como si fuera un adjetivo, o es solo una yuxtaposición de dos sustantivos y somos nosotros los que le damos el sentido de adjetivo? ¿Tiene nombre esta construcción gramatical?

Comment: ¿No será que con el tiempo se perdieron o la coma o la conjunción? "café, bar" o "café y bar"

Comment: Para mi «Café bar» es una palabra compuesta de importación. En inglés creo que  se escribe con guión.  Los abuelos decían cafetería.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece muy buena la respuesta de pablodf76, pero creo que en este caso, más que estar frente a un sustantivo que adjetiva a otro (en "reloj pulsera" *pulsera* indica el tipo de reloj, en "pollera pantalón" *pantalón* indica el tipo de pollera, con ambas piernas acampanadas como si fuera una pollera: sería inclusive más lógico decir "pantalón pollera"), estamos frente a un sustantivo compuesto que, por su ortografía o acentuación, no ha llegado a consolidarse como una sola palabra.

El de los colores me parece que es un caso aparte: dado que el color tiene un calificativo, no puede adoptar el número del sustantivo y queda en singular. Nótese que decimos "vestidos **azules**" pero "vestidos **azul claro**". El caso de "tonos mostaza" parece diferente, como que hay una preposición "de" omitida (*tonos **de** mostaza*).

El caso de "café bar" me parece más asimilable al de "casa quinta" (también "casaquinta") (ver [esta referencia](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=casaquinta)). La propiedad es **las dos cosas a la vez**: una casa y una quinta, del mismo modo que en "café bar" no me parece que un sustantivo tenga preponderancia sobre el otro, sino que se trata de un establecimiento que conjuga las dos características, la de ser un café y un bar.

Con respecto al plural, tengo las mismas dudas que Pablo. Me parece muy interesante su referencia al origen de la palabra. En inglés, *coffee bar* es, por el orden de las palabras, un bar que además es café, no al revés. La transferencia de esta palabra al castellano en el mismo orden que en inglés hace que parezca lo contrario. Simplemente lo analizaría como un sustantivo compuesto donde, al provenir del inglés, se perdió la relación entre sustantivo núcleo y sustantivo atributivo.

Answer (score 4):

Parece que en "café bar" nos encontramos ante una **aposición** de un tipo bastante particular (dos sustantivos unidos). Después de hojear bastante la NGLE no encuentro definido este tipo en particular, pero se me hace similar, funcionalmente, a la combinación *sustantivo + color* cuando el adjetivo que designa al color se trata en cambio como un sustantivo no contable ("vestidos azul claro", "tonos mostaza") [cf NGLE 13.7k].

Si aceptamos lo anterior, en "café bar" el "bar" actúa como un calificativo, casi como un adjetivo, pero es claramente invariable: el plural de "café bar", por lo menos para mí según mi instinto de hablante nativo, es "cafés bar". Sin embargo hay otras dos posibilidades:

- Por influencia del orden sintáctico del inglés yo me podría sentir tentado a interpretar "café bar" como traducción o calco de *coffee bar* (es decir, un bar de café, o sea una clase de bar).
- También podría pensarlo como un simple compuesto: "café-bar", en cuyo caso se trata de una locución formada de una manera poco habitual en castellano, pero aceptable, y su plural podría llegar a ser "café-bares".

Supongo que la segunda de estas posibilidades puede ser la correcta para algunos hablantes. Como dije, es poco habitual formar compuestos así en castellano, de manera que habrá cierta vacilación.

En Argentina se usa o usaba bastante el compuesto o locución "pollera pantalón" (con o sin guión intermedio); una pollera es una falda de mujer. En este caso el plural aceptado es "polleras pantalón". También se dice acá mucho "reloj pulsera" (pl. "relojes pulsera") sin preposición "de" intermedia; en este caso "pulsera" es claramente un calificativo nominal de "reloj" y entra dentro de las aposiciones mencionadas. Ambas locuciones me parecen sintácticamente equivalentes a "café bar".

Answer (score 1):

Café Bar es un tipo de establecimiento donde se sirve café y otro tipo de bebidas y tiene además una barra.

El nombre "café bar" se comenzó a usar en el siglo XIX para distinguirlos de los "cafés" donde el cliente permanecia sentado en una mesa y un camarero servía las bebidas. Es decir, un local que combinaba el café y la barra de bar.

Otros locales con nombre similar:

Café cantante, café teatro, y café concierto, donde además de servir las consumiciones en la mesa hay actuaciones de artistas en vivo.

Se trata de una palabra compuesta formada por dos sustantivos. Otros ejemplos:

- casa cuna
- coche cama
- disco pub
- falda pantalón
- hombre lobo
- hombre rana
- mesón restaurante
- palabra clave
- sofá cama

El plural se forma haciendo plural el primero de los sustantivos, los hombres rana, los sofás cama, etc

Comment: Creo que la pregunta es "¿Qué función [**sintáctica**] cumple "café" aquí?" Tu respuesta va más por la via semántica, explicando lo que es un café bar, pero la pregunta es sobre gramática y sintaxis.

Comment: @Diego he puesto cual es el origen y significado de "café bar" y que lo diferencia de un café  y un bar a secas.  He puesto cuando se empezó a usar y he puesto ejemplos. Otro ejemplo podria ser Disco Pub, muy de moda a partir de los 80 en España, no es una discoteca ni un pub, es ambos. A partir de ahi (palabra compuesta) se puede intuir su sintaxis fácilmente. Fíjate que no solo pregunta su función.

Comment: Cierto, pregunta la función de "café" en "café bar" y el nombre de esta construcción gramatical. Mi comentario o petición es para que en lugar de dejar que los lectores lo "intuyan fácilmente", cosa que puede ser más difícil o imposible para hablantes no nativos o para quienes no estén tan familiarizados con las normas del lenguaje, los pongas **explícitamente**. Es en tu comentario, y no en la propia respuesta, donde indicas que es una "palabra compuesta".